# Validar inicio de una lista

Tags: string, haskell, type

Estoy teniendo problemas para transformar un type a una lista, cada elemento debe ir separado por un espacio en blanco pero al realizarlo, el String tiene un espacio al inicio o final de la lista y no comprendo si hay una forma de eliminar dicho espacio. Pensé en hacer otra función que valide si era realmente el primer elemento y otra en poner un condicional, sin embargo, creo que sería un código muy extenso e innecesario.

```
type Words = [Quotes]
data Quotes = Vocals Char | One

toStr :: Words -> String
toStr [] = ""
toStr (Vocals z:zs) = " " ++ z ++ toStr zs
toStr (One :zs) = " " ++ "1" ++ toStr zs
```

Ejemplo:

```
>> toStr [(vocals 'a'), (One), (Vocals 'b')]
   " a 1 b" -- lo que retorna
   "a 1 b " -- otro error al poner el espacio al final
   "a 1 b" -- lo que debería retornar
```

Answer (score 1):

No es posible hacerlo directamente sin funciones auxiliares o parámetros adicionales. No obstante, puedes hacer uso de las funciones definidas en la biblioteca estándar.

Por ejemplo, puedes usar la función `intersperse` del módulo `Data.List` para insertar un espacio entre cada elemento de la lista previamene convertida a una lista de strings:

```hs
import Data.List(intercalate)

toStr :: Words -> String
toStr = intercalate " " . map f
    where f (Vocals x) = [x]
          f One = "1"
```

Donde `f` es la función para convertir `Quotes` a strings. Lo normal sería implementar la instancia de `Show` para tu tipo de dato `Quotes`:

```hs
instance Show Quotes where
    show (Vocals x) = [x]
    show One = "1"
```

Entonces podrías definir `toStr` directamente como:

```hs
toStr :: Words -> String
toStr = intercalate  " " . map show
```

De hecho, esta operación es tan frecuente que existe una función llamada `unwords` para juntar una lista de strings en un string, añadiendo espacios entre medias:

```hs
toStr :: Words -> String
toStr = unwords . map show
```

Comment: Y si quiero tener un dos datos unidos es posible crear una excepción con esta implementación? Soy nueva en Haskell y conozco muy poco.

Answer (score 1):

Bastaría con añadir un nuevo caso para listas de un sólo elemento:

```hs
type Words = [Quotes]
data Quotes = Vocals Char | One

toStr :: Words -> String
toStr [] = ""
toStr [One] = "1"
toStr [Vocals z] = [z]
toStr (Vocals z:zs) = [z] ++ " " ++ toStr zs
toStr (One :zs) = "1" ++ " " ++ toStr zs
```

Se puede dejar más elegante con una función auxiliar:

```hs
type Words = [Quotes]
data Quotes = Vocals Char | One

quoteToStr :: Quotes -> String
quoteToStr (Vocals z) = [z]
quoteToStr One = "1"

toStr :: Words -> String
toStr [] = ""
toStr [x] = quoteToStr x
toStr (x:xs) = quoteToStr x ++ " " ++ toStr xs
```